# R: replace the whole part of a number but keep the decimal part unchanged

Tags: r, numbers, decimal, decimalformat

ok I'm very new to R and this is a general question. I have various numbers and I want to replace the whole part and keep the decimal part unchanged.
For example I have values from 25.01 to 25.99, I want to replace 25 with 10 but keep the decimal part unchanged (so my new numbers would be from 10.01 to 10.99).
Is that possible?

Comment: So you just want to subtract 15 from each number?

Comment: This is like I need calculator to add 2 and 3.

Comment: I have about 600 observations from 25.01 to 25.99. So far I know that I can replace the value one by one but instead of doing that is there a code to replace all 600 observations at once? Something like:  if the number is between 25.01 and 25.99 replace 25 by 10 and keep the decimal values the same.

Comment: If you want to get fancy, there are integer division and modulus operators: `(25.01 %/% 1) - 15 + (25.01 %% 1)` :) If your observations are in a vector `x`, just do `x-15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commenters are right. It doesn't matter how long the list of numbers is. `R` can do the operation in one go.

```
x <- c(25.01, 25.8, 25.4)
x-15
[1] 10.01 10.80 10.40
```

If you do run into a situation with many wide-ranging numbers and need to literally keep what comes after the decimal and pick a number to put in front, use something like this:

```
keep.decimal <- function(x, n=10) {
  paste0(n, gsub('\\d*(\\.\\d*)', '\\1', x))
}
```

Then you can even choose which number you want in front of it.

```
keep.decimal(x)
[1] "10.01" "10.8"  "10.4" 
keep.decimal(x, 50)
[1] "50.01" "50.8"  "50.4"
```

## Explanation of vectorization

When a vector is defined like `x <- 1:5`, `R` will attempt to execute operations element by element when possible. If `2` had to be added to each element of `x` and assigned to a new variable `y`, it might be difficult with a `for` loop:

```
y <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  y[i] <- x[i] + 2
}
y
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

But with `R`, this operation is simplified to:

```
y <- x + 2
```

This operational technique extends further than arithmetic. Here's a problem to solve, write an expression that matches a lowercase letter to its capitalized counterpart. So turn this:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
x
[1] "a" "b" "d"
```

Into

```
y
[1] "aA" "bB" "dD"
```

I can write

```
y <- paste0(x, LETTERS[match(x, letters)])
y
[1] "aA" "bB" "dD"
```

Instead of:

```
y <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  y[i] <- paste0(x[i], LETTERS[match(x[i], letters)])
}
y
[1] "aA" "bB" "dD"
```

It is much faster too. As an analogy, think of restaurant service. `R` is your server ready to fetch what you want. If you ask your server for ketchup, they get the ketchup and deliver it. Then you ask for a napkin. They go back to get the napkin and deliver it. Then you ask for a refill.

This process takes a long time. If you would have asked for ketchup, a napkin, and a refill at the same time, the server would be able to optimize their trip to get what you want fastest. `R` has optimized functions built in the 'C' language that are lightning fast, and we exploit that speed every time we vectorize.

Comment: Maybe worth explaining how `x-15` works because of "recycling"

Comment: Never use text processing for operations on numbers.

Comment: @Roland is it due to floating point issues when converting to numeric?

Comment: @Frank Good idea, I'll add a brief explanation.

Comment: One aspect is that it is simply less efficient. E.g., here you could do `abs(x) - floor(abs(x)) + n`. Your solution doesn't work with negative numbers.

Comment: I like that. It's a better solution. Mine was meant as a hack to get the job done. More of the philosophy of get the job done first, optimize after. Yours is great because it is more general purpose. note for the negatives in mine, a slight edit helps `paste0(n, gsub('.*\\d*(\\.\\d*)', '\\1', x))`.